# I am trying to access the following multidimensional array using a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'name'    => 'Ahmed',
        'age'     => 24,
        'hobbies' => array('swimming','Drawing','Programming')
    )
);
```

The final output I am trying to achieve is:

```
My Hobbies:1)swimming 2)Drawing 3)Programming
```

Comment: `array_column($your_array, 'hobbies')`. BTW have you tried anything?

Comment: @b0s3 Don't forgot to mention that you must have `PHP version > 5.5.0` to use `array_column`

Comment: `foreach(array[$x]['hobbies'] as $i => $hobby)`

Comment: @Barmar you know you are overwriting $i all the time?

Comment: @Naruto Thx. See my answer for more reaslistic code

Comment: @Barmar much better :)

Comment: Yeah! It will not work older version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($data as $d) {
    echo "My hobbies:";
    foreach ($d['hobbies'] as $i => $h) {
        echo $i+1 . ")" . $h . " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array structure is fix try this code

```
echo "My hobbies:";
    foreach ($data[0]['hobbies'] as $Key => $value) {
        echo $Key+1 . ")" . $value . " ";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
My Hobbies:
<?php
    foreach($data[$key]['hobbies'] as $hob_key => $hobby){
        print $hob_key . ') ' . $hobby
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.